# In a UICollectionView how can I preload data outside of the cellForItemAtIndexPath to use within it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Figured out slow loading images were the behind the choppy slow effect of my collectionView.
I've been reading different Q&A's all day and various forum posts. It looks like the best way to solve this issue is to have the data pre-loaded available for the cellForItemAtIndexPath to be able to take what it needs.

I'm not sure how I can do this. I'm using parse as my backend, but sure if given a rough example I'd be able to figure out how to do it. From what I've seen so far I need a separate method to grab the data.

**Here is the code:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self objects] count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    NSArray *people = [self objects];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    VAGGarmentCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    PFObject *current;

    current = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    PFFile *userImageFile = current[@"image"];

    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        [[cell contentView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [[cell imageView] setImage:image];

    }];

    [[cell title] setText:[current valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@", [current valueForKey:@"price"]]];

    return cell;

}
```

So maybe the cellForItemAtIndexPath needs to call that method and take what it needs. Because the data would already be available it won't need to be loaded in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method and the cells will be populated immediately.

Please give suggestions and examples.

I was told a good way to do this would be to check for the image, if non existent provide a placeholder, if it does exist set it. Here are the changes to the above code.

**Updates:**

```
   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

    NSArray *people = [self objects];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    VAGGarmentCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    PFObject *current;

    current = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];



    PFFile *userImageFile = current[@"image"];

    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {

        if (!error)
        {

            if (!image) {
                [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];


            }   else {

                image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


                //resize image
                CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(158,187);
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
                [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width, destinationSize.height)];

                //New image
                UIImage*newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

                //Optimise image
                NSData *imageDataCompressed = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.4f);
                //  NSLog(@"Image Size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newImage.size));//log size of image
                    NSLog(@"%@", [current valueForKey:@"title"]);


                [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageDataCompressed]];



            }

        }

    }];


    [[cell title] setText:[current valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@", [current valueForKey:@"price"]]];


    return cell;

}
```

Place holder shows fine but remains, how do I know when the image has been loaded so I can make my cells reflect that?

Thanks for your time.
Kind regards.

**Update:**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

    NSArray *people = [self objects];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    VAGGarmentCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    PFObject *current;

    current = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];



    PFFile *userImageFile = current[@"image"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:userImageFile.url, indexPath.item]];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url                                                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad
                    timeoutInterval:6.0];
                    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                    //resize image
                    CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(158,187);
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
                    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width, destinationSize.height)];

                    //New image
                    UIImage*newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

                    //Optimise image
                    NSData *imageDataCompressed = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.4f);

                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDataCompressed];
                    NSLog(@"Image Size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newImage.size));//log size of image
                   [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

                    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError          *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to download image: %@", error);
                                        }];




    return cell;

}
```

**Latest Update:**

Set up a method that gets data from parse.com and stores in an NSMutableDictionary then in a mutable array. I store the title, price and URL to image of the garment.

```
- (void)grabDataFromCloud
{

    self.model = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (PFObject *object in [self objects]) {
        PFFile *imageFile = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageFile.url];

        NSMutableDictionary *newObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"title": [object valueForKey:@"title"], @"price": [object valueForKey:@"price"], @"imageUrl": url}];
        [[self model] addObject:newObject];
    }
}
```

This gets called in my cellForItemsAtIndexPath method.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

    [self grabDataFromCloud];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    VAGGarmentCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.activityIndicator setHidden:YES];

    NSMutableDictionary* d = [self.model objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    cell.title.text = d[@"title"];
    cell.price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%@", d[@"price"]];

    if (d[@"image"]) {
         cell.imageView.image = d[@"image"];
    } else { // if not, download it
        cell.imageView.image = nil;

        dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("test", 0);

        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

             NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:d[@"imageUrl"]];
             UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             d[@"image"] = img;
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //causes crash Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations],
                    // /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:3687
                     //   [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
                 });
        });

    }

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days the issue was my images were far too large. I had to resize them and this instantly solved my issue.

I literally narrowed things down and checked my images to find they were not being resized by the method I thought was resizing them. This is why I need to get myself used to testing.

I learnt a lot about GCD and caching in the past few days but this issue could have been solved much earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use `AFNetworking`'s [`UIImageView+AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h) category. It will handle the placeholder etc automatically, and will do everything in a background thread, ensuring that the main thread doesn't get blocked. Specifically, this is the method you'd want to call:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage;
```

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, it is working apart from the caching. The images keep being downloaded again even though I've set the cachepolicy to NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad. Looks like the images are downloaded but when I scroll I still get the chopping effect.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you to supply a placeholder image (or nil) when the image is *first* needed and to start downloading it, and then to *hang on to the image* once it has been downloaded so that ever after that you can supply it *instantly*. This example is for a table view, but the principle is exactly the same; the key thing is that my data model is a bunch of NSMutableDictionary objects, and each dictionary in not only the url for the picture we are supposed to have but also a place for keeping the image once it *has* been downloaded:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableDictionary* d = (self.model)[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = d[@"text"];
    if (d[@"im"]) { // if we have a picture, supply it
        cell.imageView.image = d[@"im"];
    } else if (!d[@"task"]) { // if not, download it
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        NSURLSessionTask* task = [self.downloader download:d[@"picurl"]
                                         completionHandler:^(NSURL* url){
            if (!url)
                return;
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage* im = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            d[@"im"] = im;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            });
        }];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: And that code is from a complete downloadable example code project that you can run on your own machine and see that it really does work (for a table view, of course): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader

Comment: Been experimenting for a while now. I load my data into an NSDictionary which is stored in a mutable. This is all put into a method that is triggered by the cellForItemAtIndex method. The titles and and prices are updated fine. I check for an image and if one isn't there I try to add one. I logged my img var to see if an image was actually there yes images are stored in the var. The last problem I have now is having that image show on the cell. I tried to reload rows at indexpaths but this causes the app to crash. You can see the error message in the code above in dispatch_get_main_queue.

Comment: Just discovered after a minute or two the app crashes by itself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach.

Google for - or use the search on SO - Asynchrnous loading. Nearly every app programmer faces this issue earlier or later. Consequentially there are tons of tutorials out there.

This is one of them. 
http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/
I think it is older than the `UICollectionView` and therfore explains it for `UITableView`. Both data source delegates are so close to each other that you can easily adopt the solution to your collection.

There are smarter ways of acomplishing your goal. But I think tht this way is a good starting point. You may later want to refactor the solution once you got comforatble with the approach in general.

Comment: Ok checked out a page which happened to be the wrong page. I took a look at that code. I understand what needs to be done, it's just how to do it. Right now my cellForItemAtIndexPath is grabbing items using URL. Then they are being cached but the chopping is still happening. I've been downsized the images and it has no effect.

Comment: When grabbing them using URL, do you do that asynchronously?

Comment: I'm certain I am. Please check latest update to my question code. This is showing the latest code.

Comment: Your last edit looks ok for me. There is just one thing. The first image, that is fully loaded, amongst a number of them that were requested, will stop the activity indicator altough the others are still on the air. But that is rather cosmetic and not related to your problem.